# ajax file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

hii i am using ajax file upload in this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="fileuploader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<div id="photo_upload">
      <div id="file-uploader_photo">       
       <noscript>          
       <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
       <!-- or put a simple form for upload here -->
       </noscript>         
      </div>
     </div>

<script language='javascript'>
new qq.FileUploader({
   element: $('#file-uploader_photo')[0],
   action: 'upload.php',
   onSubmit: function(id, fileName){
    ContentWindow.params['title'] = fileName;
    CDNAPI.validate(ContentWindow.params);
    ContentWindow.uploader.setParams(ContentWindow.params);
   },
   onComplete: function(id, fileName, content_data){
    // create content object in Gib
    App.addNewContent(content_data);
   },
   template:'<div class="qq-uploader">' + 
    '<div class="qq-upload-drop-area"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div>' +
    '<div class="qq-upload-button ui-widget-content ui-button ui-corner-all ui-state-default">Upload files</div>' +
    '<ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>' + 
        '</div>'
  });
</script>
```

but this code is giving me error this._element is undefined
[Break on this error] if (this._element.nodeType != 1){

please tell me what is the problem

using this one ...http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: I make the assumption here that your: fileuploader.js does Not use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `id="file-uploader"` element in your question, did you mean to do this instead?

```
element: $('#file-uploader_photo')[0],
//or without jQuery at all:
element: document.getElementById('file-uploader_photo'),
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mwDb8/1/).

Comment: @Rahul - It's working here with only that change: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mwDb8/ you sure you don't have the file cached or anything?

Comment: or perhaps element: $("div[id^='file-uploader_']")[0],

Comment: @Mark - Since you're using a `[0]` indexer it should be an exact/single match here ;) I would actually argue to leave jQuery out of it altogether, just `document.getElementById("file-uploader_photo")`

Comment: @Nick Craver - yes, I looked at that as well, but was making no assumptions regarding the rest of the code after viewing his code.  Probably a good idea here for your snippit as well since the [0] does return that singleton.  Seems like a wierd error and I wonder if there is some other issue in the full context of the code.

Comment: @Rahul - Is the demo I posted working for you?  If so there's something in addition to your question affecting this, is the code *exactly* as you posted? Try replacing `$('#file-uploader_photo')[0]` with `document.getElementById("file-uploader_photo")` just to take jQuery completely out of the picture.

Comment: @Mark - good point, I updated the snippet and demo here as well.

Comment: @Nick Craver - I get a "ContentWindow is undefined" error in your fiddle if I click the button.

Comment: @Mark - Sounds like a plugin error, which browser and are you running extensions/addons/plugins?

Comment: I am using IE8 in compatibility mode.  Only have the f12 developer add-in for that nothing else.  His markup template:xxx bothers me a bit, seems to be jQuery UI, but that is not in the sample.  I also pause when it is not wrapped given the jQuery selector.  I examined the plugin link and no "template:" is in those examples.(enough of my random thoughts already :)